# How to use shade plugin relocation with 3rdparty dependency injection

Tags: maven-shade-plugin

Can shade plugin modify resource and byte code such that dependency injection will us relocated packages?  I don't think it does.

I shaded and relocated **javax.transaction.TransactionManager** to org.me.shaded.javax... and my code that use it appears to function but a org.infinispan:infinispan-core attempts dependency injection using the original package name, fails to locate TransactionManager and throws this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Object.injectDependencies(..., javax.transaction.TransactionManager, ...)`

When I look in my uber jar I find infinispan-core-component-metadata.dat when contains strings referencing the javax and not the shaded package.

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>  
      <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
       <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
      <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>


      <relocations>
        <relocation>
          <pattern>javax.transaction</pattern>
          <shadedPattern>org.me.shaded.javax.transaction</shadedPattern>
        </relocation>
      </relocations> 
      <artifactSet>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>org.apache.hbase:*</exclude>
          <exclude>org.apache.ant:*</exclude>
          <exclude>org.eclipse.jetty:*</exclude>
          <exclude>org.springframework:*</exclude>
          <exclude>geronimo-spec</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </artifactSet>         
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>webapps/**</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </filter>
        <filter>
          <artifact>org.infinispan:infinispan-core</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude> <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude> <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
        <filter>
           <artifact>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifact>
           <excludes>
               <exclude>javax/transaction/**</exclude>
           </excludes>
        </filter>
        <filter>
           <artifact>javax.transaction:jta</artifact>
           <includes>
               <include>javax/transaction/**</include>
           </includes>
        </filter>
      </filters>                      
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```